# Capturing input from a serial port into a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, serial-port, barcode-scanner

Using two barcode readers connected to one machine, I have a need to store the barcode value, reader ID and datetime values in a MySQL database.

The readers are USB but are using serial port settings and so are connected via COM port. Initially I intended to capture the data via a simple web form, but needing two readers connected at the same time prevents this (due to risk of input clashes).

Firstly, does this seem feasible? If this is feasible, which language is best for me to write this in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple readers attached to your PC, you just assign them different Port numbers (which the OS will probably do automatically anyway).

There are many different languages that you could use to pass the information read by the barcode reader into your database and is really dependent on which one you have the most knowledge of, although I wouldn't recommend a web biased language like php, rather something like C#, C++, Java, VB.NET, VB, Delphi etc. Also it's best to select one that will work on your target platform.

Remember that barcode data tends to be a character string and so isn't really difficult to handle.

Comment: Thank you for your clear guidance. I do prefer web languages but searching the web for this topic gave mostly C#/VB results, which made me suspect that I should think outside of my comfort zone for this! I have some Java experience from a few years ago, so perhaps that will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use languages like Java or Vb or even C#. There are examples available for serial port programming in Java as well. One example you can find is [Here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=11). Hope this helps.